# how to add a space between two variables bash script

Tags: bash

I currently have this code,  options is empty String while k is the output string form a loop.

`options=$options$k`

How do i add a space between the variable Option and the variable k?

I want my output to look like

`Option1 Option2 Option3`

I have tried splitting using `option=$option//$k` but it gave me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just add a space. You need to *escape* the space, though, to prevent the shell from parsing the assignment as two separate words

```
options=$options\ $k
```

or more idiomatically,

```
options="$options $k"
```

Comment: this will give an extraneous leading space before the first option

Comment: I'm calling that out-of-scope; the question only asked for a space between two variables. OP can adjust this if `options` doesn't have a non-null value yet.

Answer (score 0):

Using a bash array, in your loop you can do:

```
options+=($k)
```

Afterwards, by default, when you use `${options[*]}` you will get a space-delimited string.

---

```
$ a+=(1)
$ a+=(2)
$ a+=(3)
$ echo "<${a[*]}>"
<1 2 3>
```